# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I run this code I get an error saying 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable' why does this happen?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
done = False
while not done:
    driver = webdriver.edge(executable_path ='C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe')
    driver.get("https;//www/google.co.uk/")
    sleep(10)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in the `webdriver.edge` it should be `webdriver.Edge` with a capital at the start of the browser name. This is the same for other browsers too such as `web driver.Chrome` etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
done = False
while not done:
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path ='C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe')
    driver.get("https;//www/google.co.uk/")
    sleep(10)
    driver.close()
```